# List Type Style

Tags: html, css

a very confusing thing I'm facing here.

Css

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 1em 0;
    margin: 0;
}
li {
    padding: 1em;
    display: inline;
}
li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.normalized-list{
    list-style-type: disc;
    list-style-image: none;
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding: 1em 1em;

}
.normalized-list li{
    display: block;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="normalized-list">
<li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Sadly no bullets are shown up on the li elements. Actually I don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
display: list-item;
```

not `block`.

Comment: Nice one!  It's nicely explained on e.g. w3schools, but you have to read it first :)  (http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp): "The element will generate a block box, and an inline box for the list marker"

Answer (score 0):

maybe because you display it inside and not outside the element. so that it is not visible.

```
.normalized-list{
list-style-type: disc;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
}
```

have you tested it in multiple browsers?
please try firefox with the firebug extension to see if the inheritance works as it should

Comment: I tested it at Chrome, IE and FF. I tried several positions. Nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, some browsers are quite funny when it comes to this
What I would try is the following

```
ul
{
  /*set your normal unordered list stuff*/
}

ul#specializedlist
{
  /*set your specialized list stuff*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But it is working on IE8. Firefox 3.6 is not showing the bullets. What is your expectation?